# Error when predicting on model in Keras with new image

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

Built an image classification model in Keras and when calling `predict` or `predict_classes` I receive an error - `expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (150, 150, 3)`

Here is my model:

```
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(5, activation="softmax"))
```

And the model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 148, 148, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 74, 74, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 72, 72, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 36, 36, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 34, 34, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 17, 17, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 15, 15, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 7, 7, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 6272)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               3211776   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 2565      
=================================================================
Total params: 3,455,173
Trainable params: 3,455,173
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

And here is the code I'm using to predict on the model:

```
img = load_img('rose.jpg', target_size=(150, 150, 3))
x = img_to_array(img)
x = np.reshape(x, (150, 150, 3))
model.predict(x)
```

With or without the `np.reshape` I still get the error about the shape being incorrect.

Am I reshaping the image incorrectly? Or do I need to adjust my model to be able to predict?

Comment: You have forgotten the batch dimension: `x = np.reshape(x, (1, 150, 150, 3))`.

Comment: Plus, remove that `input_shape` argument from the third `conv` layer. It is meaningless. The input shapes of middle layers are inferred automatically from the output shape of previous layer as you can see in the summary. You set the input shape of first layer because there is no previous layer.

Comment: @today Wow, thank you! I knew it was something simple like that I was missing. Feel free to put write up an answer and I'll accept.